# SSH login instead of getty with local fallback

Tags: ssh

I don't know exactly how to title my question.

Scenerio is I have a server that has a suite of TUI programs that suits my needs.

I'd like for other users of the network to turn on something smaller like a raspi or dinosaur computer, and when it boots the user isn't presented with a getty for local login as normal... they are instead presented with an ssh to the server.  Only if the server isn't answering is the user presented with a local login.

I'd imagine this type of scenerio isn't new or radical...  it's basically in my mind the concept of a thin client that connects via ssh over tcp/ip

Answer (score 9):

That is indeed quite achievable: I did something very much like that in university, back in 1998 or so.

Basically, you'll need to configure the `getty` process of the RasPi to call your own custom version of the `login` program instead of the standard `/bin/login`. That part is easy.

Your custom `login` replacement can even be a script if you don't need it to be particularly secure, or are just prototyping. But for a serious implementation, it in my opinion should be a compiled program, for security: cutting away the script interpreter minimizes the amount of code to run, and so makes it harder to set up race conditions or other attacks against it.

However, I see a possible user experience issue in your design: when the user has already entered their login name, they will probably go right on typing their password as soon as the password prompt appears, almost as a reflex action without much thinking. If a SSH connection attempt is unsuccessful and the same login name is automatically reused for a local login attempt, the user might think they've been connected to the server and be confused when they find themselves with a local login.

It might be better to require a deliberate action, such as switching to a second virtual console with an unmodified `getty` configuration, for a local login. You can add instructions on the required keystroke to `/etc/issue` so `getty` will display it before the login prompt. As a side effect, your customized `login` script or binary could then be greatly simplified to basically just:

```
#!/bin/sh
REMOTEUSER="$1"
exec ssh -oEscapeChar=none "$REMOTEUSER"@your.server.example
```

The `-oEscapeChar=none` option will prevent the use of the OpenSSH escape keystroke, so users won't be able to configure port forwardings or do other shenanigans with the SSH client (thanks to Ferrybig for reminding me!).

Since `login` (or any substitute for it) will run as root, it would be better to switch to some non-root user before `exec()`ing the `ssh` command. This is where a compiled program would be more flexible.

If you have even the slightest experience in programming, I'd recommend you to download the source code package for `/bin/login` of your Linux distribution of choice, and seeing if you can hack it into doing this.

Basically you would need to make two changes: instead of using the username given to it as a parameter by `getty` for selecting the username to login as, you'd make your substitute `login` use a hard-coded username you'll reserve for outgoing SSH connections only. And instead of `exec()`ing the user's shell at the end of the login process, you would `exec()` the SSH command, giving it as parameters the username you got from `getty` and the name of your server.

Comment: I would advice passing `-oEscapeChar=none`, otherwise people logging in via this method can add local/remote/dynamic port forwardings

Comment: @Ferrybig That's indeed a good point, added.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to do this in `/etc/profile`, with something like this (which assumes that the user's shell is bash or ksh or something else that uses `/etc/profile`):

```bsh
if [[ $(ps h -o cmd $(ps h -o ppid $$)) =~ $(basename "$SHELL") ]] \
   || id | grep -q '(sshgroup)' \
   && fping -q remotehost; then
  set -e   # exit on any error, incl. user pressing ^C during
           # ssh-keygen or ssh-copy-id

  # generate a key if it doesn't already exist
  if [ ! -e ~/.ssh/id_rsa ] then
    ssh-keygen
  fi

  # install it on remote host if ~/.ssh/key-installed doesn't exist
  if [ ! -e ~/.ssh/key-installed ] ; then
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remotehost
    touch ~/.ssh/key-installed
  fi

  # rewrite the following if any users have a shell which doesn't
  # support arrays (ash, dash, posix sh, etc)
  ssh_args=(-oEscapeChar=none)
  exec ssh "${ssh_args[@]}" remotehost
fi
```

In English: if the parent process isn't the user's shell **AND** the user is a member of `sshgroup` **AND** the remote host is responding to pings then ssh to remotehost (and because `ssh` is `exec`-ed, the user will be logged out as soon as the ssh session is ended).  Otherwise login proceeds as usual.   Group membership is tested before `fping` so that non-members don't have to wait for the `fping`` result.

Appropriate messages in the `/etc/motd` files on the local and remote hosts can be used to highlight which machine they've ended up on.

If the user doesn't have their ssh key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host, then it will ask for their password too.  The `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` stuff in the script fragment is a bare-minimum example of how to prevent this.  It should probably also run `ssh-agent` with `-t 86400` so they only have to type their key's passphrase once/day, not every time they login.

Checking group membership like this makes it easy to exclude certainly users (like root, or a non-root admin account) from being auto-sshed to the remote host.  You could invert the test and auto-ssh any user who **isn't** a member of a particular group.